# Problemas al mostrar información a partir de un select dinámico

Tags: javascript, php, java, laravel

tengo un tabla de artículos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven hay un área de almacén ya que estoy trabajando con un sistema de inventario en donde un artículo puede estar almacenado en uno o más almacenes, y según el almacén, el stock disponible es distinto. Mi objetivo es que al yo seleccionar el almacén en el select se me muestre el stock que tiene disponible ese artículo dentro del almacén seleccionado, y mientras que en el primero me funciona, en cualquier otra fila no. Y si, además, yo doy click en 'agregar' después no me sigue haciendo la función, ya no me aparece nada. ¿Podrían ayudarme?

Esta es mi función:

```
$(".js-agregar").on("click", function(){
        fila = $(this).closest("tr");
        agregar(fila);
    });

    var cont = 1;
    total = 0;

    $("#guardar").hide();
    $(".js-almacen-id").change(mostrarValores);

    function mostrarValores() {
        datosProducto = document.getElementById('almacen_id').value.split('_');

        $("#stock").val(datosProducto[1]);
    };

    var almacen_id = $('.js-almacen-id');

    almacen_id.change(function(event) {
    const index = $(event.target).attr('index')
    var articulo_id = $(event.target).attr('.js-articulo-id')
    $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('get_products_by_id') }}",
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                almacen_id: event.target.value,
            },
            success: function(data) {

                $(".js-stock").eq(index).val(data.disponible);
                $(".js-almacen-id").eq(index).val(data.almacen_id);
                $(".js-articulo-id").eq(index).val(data.articulo_id);
            }
        });

    });
```

Y mi función de agregar al carrito:

```
function agregar(fila) {

        articulo_id = fila.find(".js-articulo-id").val();
        articulo = fila.find(".js-articulo-nombre").val();
        cantidad = fila.find(".js-cantidad").val();
        almacen_id = fila.find(".js-almacen-id").val();
        stock = $("#stock").val();

        if (articulo_id != "" && cantidad != "" && cantidad > 0 && articulo_id != null) {
            if (parseInt(stock) >= parseInt(cantidad)) {
                subtotal[cont] = cantidad * precio_compra;
                total = total + subtotal[cont];
                var fila = '<tr class="selected" id="fila' + cont +
                    '"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar(' + cont +
                    ');"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td><td><input type="hidden" name="articulo_id[]" value="' +
                    articulo_id + '">' + articulo +
                    '</td><td> <input type="hidden" name="almacen_id[]" value="' + almacen_id +
                    '"> <input class="form-control" type="number" value="' + almacen_id +
                    '" disabled> </td><td> <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cantidad[]" value="' + cantidad +
                    '"></td> <td><input type="text" name="comentario[]" class="form-control" required></td></tr>';
                cont++;
                limpiar();
                totales();
                evaluar();
                $('#detalles').append(fila);
            } else {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    text: 'La cantidad a vender supera el stock.',

                })
            }
        } else {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                text: 'Rellene todos los campos del detalle del pedido.',

            })
        }
    }
```

Y así está el `get_products_by_id` en mi controlador de artículos:

```
public function get_products_by_id(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $articulos = DetalleArticulo::where('almacen_id', $request->almacen_id, 'articulo_id', $request->articulo_id)->firstOrFail();
        return response()->json($articulos);
    }
}
```

Mi tabla de artículos es la siguiente:

```
<table class="table table-striped mt-0.5 table-bordered shadow-lg mt-4" id="articulo">
                <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" width='60px'>Código</th>
                        <th scope="col">Imagen</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                        <th scope="col">Categoría</th>
                        <th scope="col">Almacén</th>
                        <th scope="col">Disponible</th>
                        <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                        <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($articulos as $articulo)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $articulo->codigo }}</td>
                            @if (isset($articulo->imagen))
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <img src="/imagen/{{$articulo->imagen}}" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; border-radius: 20%;">
                                </td>
                            @else
                                <td class="text-center"><img src="/imagen/caja.png"
                                        alt="" width="70" height="70"></td>
                            @endif
                            <td>{{ Str::ucfirst($articulo->nombre) }}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ Str::ucfirst($articulo->categoria->nombre) }}</td>
                            <td>
                            <select class="form-control selectpicker articuloB js-almacen-id" data-live-search="true" name="almacen_id" id="almacen_id" lang="es" index={{$articulo->id}}>
                                <option value="" data-icon="fas fa-box" disabled selected>Buscar almacén</option>
                                @foreach ($detallearticulos as $detallearticulo)
                                @if ($detallearticulo->articulo_id == $articulo->id)
                                <option value="{{ $detallearticulo->almacen_id }}">{{ $detallearticulo->almacen_id }} - {{ $detallearticulo->almacen->nom_alm }}</option>
                                @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 50px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="stock" id="stock" class="form-control js-stock" disabled>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control js-cantidad" min="0" max="100" name="cantidad" step="1"
                                    oninput="validity.valid||(value='')">
                                @if ($errors->has('cantidad'))
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                        <span class="error text-danger">{{ $errors->first('cantidad') }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control js-articulo-id" name="articulo_id" value="{{$articulo->id}}">
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control js-articulo-nombre" name="articulo_nombre" value="{{$articulo->nombre}}">
    
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right mt-1 js-agregar"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Agregar</button>
                                </div>                             
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: No puedes usar id, necesitas usar clases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el problema en tu codigo es que estas utilizando un id para recuperar tus select con jquery y asignarles un evento "change", esto hace que tu evento solo sea aplicado al primer elemento que se encuentra con este id, ya que se utilizan los id en HTML para elementos unicos y asi tambien lo interpreta jQuery, en lugar de esto debes de utilizar clases en vez de ids si es un elemento que se repite constantemente en tu documento HTML, por lo que tu select debería quedar asi.

```
<select class="almacen_id">
</select>
```

Y al recuperar y asignar un evento a tus select debes recuperar la clase de tu select para que este evento se aplique a todos los select que tengas con esa clase, a la vez que el valor que selecciono el usuario es ideal que lo recuperes con el objeto Event entregado como parametro a la funcion que ejecute tu evento, esto quedaria de la siguiente manera.

```
var almacen_id = $('.almacen_id');

almacen_id.change(function(event) {

  $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('get_products_by_id') }}",
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            almacen_id: event.target.value,
        },
        success: function(data) {

            //Modificar otras columnas de la fila 
            $("#stock").val(data.disponible);
            $("#articulo_id").val(data.articulo_id);
            $("#almacen_id").val(data.almacen_id);
        }
    });

});
```

Ahora el mismo problema tienes al modificar los valores #stock, #articulo_id y #almacen_id, este ultimo redundante por lo que lo omitiria. Al utilizar ids para estos elementos html solamente estas modificando el valor del primer elemento que se encuentre en tu documento HTML, por lo que estos elementos tambien debes asignarle una clase en vez de un id. Para recuperarlos y modificar su valor, te sugiero entregarle a tu select un atributo en el que especifiques a que fila de tu tabla corresponde, de esta manera podrás recuperar este atributo en tu evento change y modificar los valores necesarios de esa misma fila.

Para esto tus select deben contener el atributo "index" de la siguiente manera.

```
<select class="almacen_id" index=0>
</select>

<select class="almacen_id" index=1>
</select>
```

Y tu evento change quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
var almacen_id = $('.almacen_id');

almacen_id.change(function(event) {
  const index = $(event.target).attr('index')
  $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('get_products_by_id') }}",
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            almacen_id: event.target.value,
        },
        success: function(data) {

            //Recupera el elemento con clase stock y articulo_id que coincida con el index del select modificado
            $(".stock").eq(index).val(data.disponible);
            $(".articulo_id").eq(index).val(data.articulo_id);
        }
    });

});
```

Te dejo un ejemplo donde se aplica lo mencionado anteriormente de forma mas rudimentaria.

```js
var almacen_id = $('.almacen_id');

almacen_id.change(function(event) {

  //Recupera el atributo index del select modificado
  const index = $(event.target).attr('index')
  
  //Imprime el valor del option seleccionado
  console.log("Valor: "+event.target.value)
  
  //Imprime el index del select seleccionado
  console.log("Index: "+index)
  
  //Modifica el elemento con clase .stock que coincida con el indice del select modificado
  $('.stock').eq(index).text("Este fue modificado")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="almacen_id" index=0>
  <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opcion 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opcion 3</option>
  <option value="4">Opcion 4</option>
</select>

<select class="almacen_id" index=1>
  <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opcion 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opcion 3</option>
  <option value="4">Opcion 4</option>
</select>

<select class="almacen_id" index=2>
  <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opcion 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opcion 3</option>
  <option value="4">Opcion 4</option>
</select>

<p class="stock">Stock select 1</p>
<p class="stock">Stock select 2</p>
<p class="stock">Stock select 3</p>
```

Saludos, te adjunto enlaces con lectura sugerida para entender mejor lo dicho anteriormente.

https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

https://api.jquery.com/change/

https://api.jquery.com/eq/

https://api.jquery.com/attr/

**ACTUALIZACION**

Tu código no esta recuperando la información del articulo que estas modificando porque no estas enviando este parametro a tu controlador. Para esto puedes especificar el id de tu articulo en tu un atributo de tu select por lo que quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker articuloB js-almacen-id" data-live-search="true" name="almacen_id" id="almacen_id" lang="es" index={{$loop->index}} data-articulo-id={{$articulo->id}}>
      <option value="" data-icon="fas fa-box" disabled selected>Buscar almacén</option>
      @foreach ($detallearticulos as $detallearticulo) 
        @if ($detallearticulo->articulo_id == $articulo->id)
        <option value="{{ $detallearticulo->almacen_id }}">{{ $detallearticulo->almacen_id }} - {{ $detallearticulo->almacen->nom_alm }}</option>
        @endif 
      @endforeach
 </select>
```

Aqui te recomiendo que utilices la variable $loop->index para asignar el atributo index a tu select, este valor esta disponible en el Loop @foreach en tus plantillas blade.

Luego en tu evento change de tu select, debes agregar el id de tu articulo a tu solicitud HTTP a tu controlador PHP, por lo que debería quedarte de la siguiente manera.

```
var almacen_id = $('.js-almacen-id');

almacen_id.change(function(event) {

  //Recuperas el atributo index añadido a tu select
  const index = $(event.target).attr('index')

  //recuperas el atributo data-articulo-id añadido a tu select
  const articulo_id = $(event.target).attr('data-articulo-id')

  $.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('get_products_by_id') }}",
    method: 'GET',
    data: {
      almacen_id: event.target.value,
      //Añades tu el id de tu articulo a tu solicitud HTTP
      articulo_id: articulo_id
    },
    success: function(data) {

      $(".js-stock").eq(index).val(data.disponible);
      $(".js-almacen-id").eq(index).val(data.almacen_id);
      $(".js-articulo-id").eq(index).val(data.articulo_id);
    }
  });

});
```

Y luego en tu función get_products_by_id en tu controlador esta mal tu función where, en tu caso deseas recuperar tu DetalleArticulo cuando el almacen_id sea el recibido en tu funcion **Y** el articulo_id sea el recibido en tu funcion.

Por lo que esto correspondería en SQL a una clausula WHERE (condicion1) AND (condicion2).

Para replicar esta clausula utilizando Eloquent en Laravel, una de las opciones es entregarle un array a tu funcion where, de la siguiente manera.

```
$articulos = DetalleArticulo::where(['almacen_id' => $request->almacen_id, 'articulo_id' => $request->articulo_id])->firstOrFail();
```

O tambien puedes realizarlo separando tus condiciones en 2 funciones where de la siguiente manera:

```
$articulos = DetalleArticulo::where('almacen_id', $request->almacen_id)->where('articulo_id', $request->articulo_id)->firstOrFail();
```

Con esto debería funcionar tu código como lo deseas, te recomiendo que cuando este funcione busques otras formas de realizar esto mismo utilizando menos código, de esta manera mejoraras tu logica a la hora de escribir tu código y te familiarizaras más con los recursos utilizados.

Te adjunto otros enlaces de lectura recomendada relacionados con los recursos utilizados.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#where-clauses

Saludos, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: si tengo un ``foreach`` que es el que me da los artículos y a su vez un ``foreach`` para que me dé los almacenes a los que pertenece cada artículo, ¿cómo puedo poner un index para cada select y el input donde este se debería mostrar?

Comment: Imagino que al ser datos dinamicos, al momento de recuperar los articulos generas el contenido de cada fila de la tabla incluyendo el select con JS . Ahi es donde puedes incluir el atributo index en tus select.

Comment: ahora cuaquier select me trae los datos del primer artículo, y me los coloca en el input de ese artículo. O sea, no importa el select del artículo que elija, todos me traen los datos del primero.

Comment: Lo lamento, no me fije que estabas utilizando plantillas blade, para agregar el atributo index a tus select utiliza $loop->index dentro de tu foreach de articulos, no utilices el id de tu articulo, otro punto importante es que en tu funcion "get_products_by_id" recibes el id de tu articulo, el cual en tu codigo js no estas enviando, puedes establecer este como otro atributo en tu select nombrandolo "data-articulo-id" y recuperarlo en tu evento change utilizando "$(event.target).attr('data-articulo-id')", de esta manera podrás enviarlo en tu solicitud http a tu controlador.

Comment: logré que se mostrara el stock en la línea en la que se está modificando el select, el problema ahora es que me sigue trayendo los datos del primero, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que según el id del artículo me muestre la cantidad disponible de ese artículo en el almacén seleccionado?

Comment: genial, actualiza tu pregunta con tu código actual para poder seguir ayudándote por favor, saludos.

Comment: ya lo edité, aprecio mucho su ayuda

Comment: Actualice la respuesta, espero que te ayude, saludos.